# Best way to display a "High Scores" Results

Tags: iphone, xcode

First, I would to thank everyone for all the help they provide via this website.  It has gotten me to the point of almost being able to release my first iPhone app!

Okay, so the last part I have is this:  I have a game that allows users to save their high scores.  I update a plist file which contains the users Name, Level, and score.

Now I want to create a screen that will display the top 20 high scores.  What would be the best way to do this?  At first I thought possibly creating an HTML file with this info but am not even sure if that is possible.  I would need to read the plist file, and then write it out as HTML.  Is this possible?  To write a file out as HTML?

Or an even better question, is there a better way?

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Geo...

Comment: While not about the display side, this similar question might also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367198/iphone-high-scores-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `UITableView` was made for. Read your plist into an array and feed the contents to the table view through its datasource/delegate methods.

Comment: But will I be able to display the three "columns" of data for each row? Meaning one row would contain: Name, Level, Score?

Comment: Sure if you customize the design of the table cells.